# How do i configure Google Identity Platform properly?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openid, identity

We want to let users login with Google in our web app.
On our intranet we want to an OpenID provider to let users in into 3rd party apps, so they are automatically logged in. (SSO)

3rd party apps (like dropbox) can be configured. I need a login-url and certificate to make it work.
I think that those should be provided on the "credentials" section, after configuring an Identity provider in the Identity Platform. But that isn't the case.

I created an identity in the Google Identity Platform. I choose "openid connect" as provider and i entered the client id and secret i found in the credentials of the OAuth 2.0 Client ID.
After saving i should expect that the loginurl and the certificate is available in the Credentials, but noth are not available. What am i doing wrong?

(this secret is hidden for now. but i am sure it is correct)

[image: openid configuration]

Comment: Are you mixing Firebase and Google? Are you also trying to setup SAML? What documentation are you following? For IDP SSO start here: https://cloud.google.com/architecture/identity/single-sign-on#single_sign-on_process and here: https://cloud.google.com/identity/solutions/enable-sso Edit your post will better details.

Comment: Thanks John, It seems like i was mixing things up then. pointing me to this documentation made me realize i need to be in de Google Admin console, to get the login-url and the pem certificate. The documentation is clear. This is what i was looking for: https://support.google.com/a/answer/12032922?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Posting as a community based on the comment of @AlainVanderbroeck:

> It seems like i was mixing things up then. pointing me to this documentation made me realize i need to be in de Google Admin console, to get the login-url and the pem certificate. The documentation is clear. This is what i was looking for: [Set up SSO for your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/12032922?hl=en)